# Difficulties introducing hash table lookup into pipeline

Tags: powershell

Excuse my terminology but I'm quite new to Powershell.
I'm trying to write code that takes output from invoke-sqlcmd and then translates on of the objects using a hash table (from database id to database name). My code is as follows:-

```
$ht=@{}
invoke-sqlcmd -serverinstance $dsname -query "select id=database_id,name=name from sys.databases" |
  Select-Object id,name |
  Foreach-Object {$ht.Add($_.id,$_.name)}

$DBCCShrinkOutput += Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $dsname -Database master -inputfile $DBCCFile |
  Select-Object @{n="Instance";e={$dsname}},
    **@{n="DBName";e={$ht.$($_.dbid)}},** 
    FileID, 
    CurrentSize,
    MinimumSize, 
    UsedPages, 
    EstimatedPages |
  Sort-Object
```

The problem is that, whatever combination of @ and$ I try in the DBName translation, it doesn't get any value from the $ht hash table, despite that table being properly populated, and pops out of the pipeline with a blank in the DBName.

Any suggestions would be very welcome.

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to achieve? Maybe there's better a way, but figuring it out requires information about the actual task. That being said, unless you really know what you are doing, [stop shrinking](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/08/stop-shrinking-your-database-files-seriously-now/) the databases.

Comment: I agree about not shrinking the databases and it is only the log files that are in scope.

Comment: The actual task being undertaken is shrinking the log files using DBCC and taking the output from that command to produce a report outlining what has been done. The output from DBCC contains DBID and not DBName, hence the attempt to convert by looking up a hash table populated using "select id=database_id,name=name from sys.databases"

Answer (score 0):

To use the dbid as the key to retrieve the database name would look something like this.

```
@{n="DBName";e={$ht[$_.dbid]}}
```

Assuming dbid is one of the columns in the query result.

Comment: Yes, I agree but that still throws a blank. If I omit the conversion and just leave the column as DBID is populated properly, with the DBID, which is not what I want